# Error when Running PyInstaller-Generated Executable for Excel Automation Script

Tags: python, excel, pyinstaller

I created a code in which I automate the filling of an Excel spreadsheet with data from a Google website, and it works fine when executed directly in VS Code. However, when I create an executable of this code with PyInstaller and run it, I get the following error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "auto_fill.py", line 193, in <module>
  File "auto_fill.py", line 191, in display_window
  File "auto_fill.py", line 18, in run_code
  File "openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 344, in load_workbook
  File "openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 123, in __init__
  File "openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 95, in _validate_archive
  File "zipfile.py", line 1284, in __init__
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\mathe\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Programming\\MyProjects\\Automation\\Ecosul Spreadsheet 2\\dist\\spreadsheet'
```

This is the error I'm encountering. What could be causing it when running the executable created with PyInstaller?

I tried creating an executable for my Excel automation script using PyInstaller, and I was expecting the executable to work correctly, filling the Excel spreadsheet with data from a Google website. However, I encountered an error when running the executable, as described in the traceback above. I am looking for solutions to resolve this issue and make the executable work as expected.